# Fast copy of TList <T>?

Tags: delphi, collections, delphi-xe

Is there a fast way to copy a generic TList?

```
Copy.Capacity := List.Count;
for Item in List do
  Copy.Add (Item);
```

is very slow. There seems to be no way to use `CopyMemory` since I can't get the memory adress of the internal array (which is obvious from an information hiding viewpoint). I miss something like

```
List.Copy (Copy);
```

which uses the knowledge of the internal representation to improve performance. Can it be done?

Comment: `TList<T>.AddRange()` has 3 overloaded versions. only one of them uses TArray as parameter

Comment: @teran: you are right. But it turns out that `AddRange` implementation is not faster. I removed that confusing sentence from the question.

Comment: And there goes the non-constructive downvoter again...could you please at least leave a comment?

Comment: +1 from the upvoter (: this question is more than reasonable!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the generic `TList<T>` it is simply not possible to implement the function you want. That's because copy the contents of `T` may involve more than a simple memory copy. If `T` contains any managed types (i.e. strings, interfaces etc.) then the reference counts on those managed objects must be incremented.

- If your `T` does contain managed types then I doubt that you can do much better then the code you already have.
- If your `T` does not contain any managed types then a memory copy is viable but you will need to create your own class to encapsulate this list since `TList<T>` is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You always can reinterpret of memory.

```
type
  TListHack<T> = class(TEnumerable<T>)
  private
    FItems: array of T;
    FCount: Integer;
  public
    class procedure FastAdd(Source, Dest: TList<T>);
  end;

{ TListHack<T> }

class procedure TListHack<T>.FastAdd(Source, Dest: TList<T>);
var
  SourceHack: TListHack<T>;
  DestHack: TListHack<T>;
  TI: PTypeInfo;
begin
  TI := TypeInfo(T);
  if not (TI.Kind in [tkInteger, tkChar, tkFloat,
    tkSet, tkClass, tkMethod, tkWChar, tkInt64, tkClassRef, tkPointer, tkProcedure]) then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Type %s is not supported', [TI.Name]);

  if Source.Count = 0 then
    Exit;
  DestHack := TListHack<T>(Dest);
  SourceHack := TListHack<T>(Source);
  if Dest.Capacity < Dest.Count + Source.Count then
    Dest.Capacity := Dest.Count + Source.Count;

  Move(SourceHack.FItems[0], DestHack.FItems[Dest.Count], Source.Count * SizeOf(T));
  DestHack.FCount := DestHack.FCount + Source.Count;
end;

procedure TForm6.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Source, Dest: TList<Integer>;
  Arr: TArray<Integer>;
begin
  Source := TList<Integer>.Create;
  Dest := TList<Integer>.Create;
  try
    Source.Add(1); Source.Add(2); Source.Add(3);
    Dest.Add(10);
    TListHack<Integer>.FastAdd(Source, Dest);
    Assert(Dest.Count = 4);
    ShowMessageFmt('%d, %d, %d, %d', [Dest[0], Dest[1], Dest[2], Dest[3]]);
  finally
    Source.Free; Dest.Free;
  end;

  TListHack<IUnknown>.FastAdd(TList<IUnknown>.Create, TLIst<IUnknown>.Create); // exception
end;
```

But it's very dangerously

Comment: Yes, that's indeed very dangerously. Any change in object layout of `TList <T>` will break it - additional to the point about managed types that David mentioned. I guess that's no option for me.

Comment: Some very popular components (VirtualTree for example) use this hack to workaround VCL bugs.  You decide..  You can use standart TList<>.Add for managed types and FastCopy for Integer/Double etc..

Comment: You may as well write your own list class as do this.

Comment: Yes, I think a custom list class with generic constraints would be much better.

Comment: @Smasher I don't think you can constrain the generic type sufficiently.

Comment: @David: I thought about a `class` constraint, but now that I think about it...what's with the references inside the object? If the object itself contains managed types, it does not work right? What if the list class would check if the object implements `IInterface` and then call `_AddRef` and `_Release` explicitly?

Comment: @Smasher Then you'd have the same performance as the code in the Q. You are only going to gain speed up if your items have no managed types.