# How to use generic TList List property

Tags: delphi, generics

DelphiXE7 Update1

While trying to work with the TList.List property I noticed an odd behavior. If you look at the following code it seems that the array size returned by MyList1.List is not correct... So, where the bug? Is it in my code/head or within the RTL ;-)

```
var
  MyList1, MyList2: TList<String>;
begin
  MyList1 := TList<String>.Create;
  MyList2 := TList<String>.Create;

  MyList1.Add('A');
  MyList1.Add('B');
  MyList1.Add('C');

  MyList2.AddRange(MyList1.List);   // MyList1.Count = 4 !!!!

  ShowMessage(Format('%d, %d', [MyList1.Count, MyList2.Count]));
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Use just `MyList2.AddRange(MyList1);`. `List` is a property that should not have been `public`, IMHO. Anyway, [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9479089/960757) and [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26721955/960757) is something you might be interested in.

Comment: TLama. You are too fast ;-)  I have just edited the code in order to rephrase the "real" concern. Not the assign itself but the faulty (?) TList<T>.List property.

Comment: Then you may take a look at [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22713780/960757).

Comment: It's an RTL design flaw. `List` property reads `FList` field, while it should call `ToArray` method instead.

Comment: @FreeConsulting - it's not a design flaw. If `List` called `ToArray`, then there would be no point in having `List`. It's an analogue to the `List` property you had (have) in a non-generic `TList`, for better or for worse.

Comment: @Free It's an actively taken design decision to let consumers gain access to the contained objects. For instance, this allows items to be passed as var parameters and avoid copying. Original implementations of `TList<T>` did not contain this property which was added, I think, in XE3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `List` property is the raw underlying storage. The class, as an optimisation to reduce the number of re-allocations, over allocates this storage. This has the effect that the array return by `List` may have more elements than the list itself. You can then add more items without forcing re-allocation until the capacity is reached.

The behaviour is thus to be expected. Use `Count` to find out how many items in the list are defined.